# Retrieving raster/coverage width and height in pixels from GeoServer

Tags: python, raster, geoserver, rest, extents

Is it possible to retrieve the original width and height in pixels for a coverage in GeoServer using either the Python API or REST?  I could not find anything in the documentation regarding how to retrieve height or width of a coverage in GeoServer.

Here is my current solution interfacing with GeoServer.  It needs GDAL, and it will probably fail if the coverage is not a simple file readable by GDAL (i.e. a PostGIS raster)

```
import gdal
import os
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog

#...code

#store is a GeoServer store
def get_raster_dimensions(store):                                           
    """ Get the size of the raster from the catalog. """                    
    gdal.UseExceptions()        
    #this, of course will fail if the data isn't a regular file                                            
    base_url = store.url.replace('file:', '', 1)                            
    #what if the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR is unset?  How to find it then?         
    coverage_path = os.path.join(os.environ['GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR'], base_url)
    #if the coverage store is a raster readable by GDAL,                    
    #we can get the dimensions with GDAL                                                      
    try:                                                                    
        dataset = gdal.Open(coverage_path)                                  
        return (dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterYSize)                   
    except RuntimeError:                                                    
        return (None, None)                                                 
    finally:                                                                
        #no close method in GDAL docs, this was referenced as the way       
        #to clean up the file after finished                                
        dataset = None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an easier method using Python via OWSLib when the workspace name, layer name, and WCS service endpoint are specified

```
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService

def get_raster_dimensions(workspace, name, server_url):                                      
    """ Get the size of the raster using OWSLib                            
        Returns a list of strings """                                            
    wcs = WebCoverageService(server_url + 'wcs', '1.0.0') 
    grid = wcs.contents[workspace + ':' + name].grid                             
    return [str(int(h) - int(l) + 1) for                                         
            h, l in zip(grid.highlimits, grid.lowlimits)]
```